# Invalid Report generation using Xl.generateReport in Selenium TestNG

Tags: java, excel, selenium, maven, testng

I have created a selenium webdriver project and I am using TestNg, Maven.
I want to generate report in excel format here. After searching online and looking at some videos I am using Xl.generateReport for excel report generation. I am looking at below video and have done the steps as shown in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VVi185e6DI

So now I have my testng.xml file that has 2 test suites and total 5 testcases. After I run this testng.xml file, the console shows that all 5 testcases have been passed.
But when I see the report that is generated, it does not execute both the suites. It executes only one suite from testng file and skips one suite.

Also, the testcase pass/fail that is shown in excel report is wrong. It shows some testcase fail and some passed but the console in Eclipse shows all testcases are passed.
also the date of execution, the exceptions shown in excel report, all is wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!!! Please provide some code and configuration snippets, it really helps in identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to update the Maven project and refresh the Reports folder to see valid test results.
It worked for me.
Thanks.